# Adobe Acrobat XI Scrolls too fast on large documents

Tags: adobe-acrobat, scrolling

When using acrobat XI on Windows 10, I notice that in large documents (> 50-100 pages) it scrolls way too fast when using my touchpad. In smaller documents, it scrolls a reasonable speed. Originally, I hypothesized that there would be a setting that allowed me to control what designates a "large document" that would trigger the fast scrolling speed. I found one such setting under settings, but it has not had an effect on the scrolling speed. Now, I don't really know what to try next.

Has anyone had this issue and fixed it?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I think Adobe is too lazy to fix this bug.

Comment: This is my complaint to them from 2016, still active till now with no solution with a lot of people having the same problem:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2240294

Comment: I gave up and use Firefox as my PDF viewer instead. The *main* thing I expect from my PDF viewer: to be able to read (potentially large) PDF documents in a continuous mode. If I get lost whenever I scroll (which I do for almost every line I read) I lose context and my job goes from accumulating knowledge to finding where I was.